# OpenSSL error savon nginx unicorn, sslv3 alert unexpected message

Tags: ruby, nginx, openssl, unicorn, savon

Having a hard time getting up and running with rails (3.1) app on private vps (Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS).

Getting error below when using savon to call a soap service

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: sslv3 alert unexpected message):
lib/modules/soap_client.rb:32:in `create_payment'
app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:34:in `create'
```

Strange as this exactly same application code works without a problem over at **Heroku** were I hosting it now as a result.

It seems to be a server side issue.

Anyone else with similar problem using **savon** togeheter with **nginx**, **unicorn** & ubuntu 10.04?

Also tried set savon to ignore SSL validation with

```
@client = Savon::Client.new do
     http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none
     wsdl.document = SOAP_URL
end
```

Savon version is 0.9.9

Ruby version 1.9.2p180

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a solution for you, but the first thing I'd look into is OpenSSL versions on both servers. Heroku may be providing an updated or patched version that isn't available on Ubuntu 10.04.

Also, I'd check by manually running OpenSSL s_client on your ubuntu system:

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -host <fqdn> -port <port>
```

That will help isolate the issue to OpenSSL, assuming that's where the problem lies.